# AWS step functions task success callback using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

**Overview**

When using the `start_execution` method for an AWS Step Function with the SDK for Python (Boto3) I have added a 'time.sleep(6)' call to allow the step function execution to complete as a temporary fix.

If I don't add this the function execution fails as the state machine has not completed.

**Code**

```
def runStateMachine(dictInput):
    response = client.start_execution(
        stateMachineArn=arn,
        input=json.dumps(dictInput))
    time.sleep(6)
    executionArn = response["executionArn"]
    desc_exec_resp = client.describe_execution(
        executionArn=executionArn)
    return json.loads(desc_exec_resp["output"])
```

**Question**

Can I use some kind of callback or token to complete this without the sleep call?

If I understand correctly this [SendTaskSuccess](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskSuccess.html) API call may be what I need, but I can't find any code examples.

Comment: [DescribeExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_DescribeExecution.html) results are best effort and may not reflect very recent updates and changes. So the sleep makes sense. Why avoid the sleep?

Answer (score 1):

I am curious how you can catch the status back in the same lambda invocation without waiting. Even if you are using a callback, it will end up in a totally separate invocation of lambda depending on the lambda concurrency settings.

API Call [SendTaskSuccess](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_SendTaskSuccess.html) used in [Callbacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token) pattern where a workflow is paused until a task token is returned. The task will pause until it receives that task token back with a `SendTaskSuccess` or `SendTaskFailure` call.

I would break this handle execution output part into a separate lambda,  save money and time.

For that, you can have a [EventBridge (CloudWatch Events) for Step Functions execution status changes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-events.html) configured which can invoke your lambda about the full details. Below is an example of `SUCCEEDED` state of step function execution, and you can hook your lambda to it.

```
{
  "source": ["aws.states"],
  "detail-type": ["Step Functions Execution Status Change"],
  "detail": {
    "status": ["SUCCEEDED"],
    "stateMachineArn": ["arn:aws:states:eu-central-1:1234567890:stateMachine:Mapstate", ""]
  }
}
```

Callbacks are might not be good for this flow.  Below is an example of [send_task_success](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.42/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.send_task_success)

[Callback Pattern Example (Amazon SQS, Amazon SNS, Lambda)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/callback-task-sample-sqs.html)

```py
import boto3

step_functions = boto3.client('stepfunctions')

def handler(event, context):
    # extract token from the event

    task_token = event['taskToken']
    step_functions.send_task_success(
        taskToken=task_token,
        output='json output of the task'
    )
```

Comment: Can you please provide an implementation example using the code from the question? I'm still unclear how this should be done.  Thanks

Comment: @ade1e `SendTaskSuccess` task is not doing what you suggested in the question. You have to wait if you want to check the output of the step function in the same lambda.  I described another way using `event rule` which triggers another lambda if step function exits as `SUCCEEDED ` and you can do `describe_execution`  and eventually extract the output.

Comment: `runStateMachine` is a function running locally on my Mac and not a Lambda.

Comment: @ade1e in that case you are left with waiting only or have watcher on describing the execution id.